# Paper fold animation in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Hi I am developing an animation in which flip animation is required as shown in http://www.avatar-app.com/dev/2012/01/24/ios-flip-transform/ (Similar to weatherflow app in wp7). Now I am successful in achieving this by making use of two border one above the other and animating one border using planeprojection. And here is my code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Wheat" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                   <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="planeProjection"    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationX" From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:5" />

                </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Border Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0" ManipulationStarted="Border_ManipulationStarted">

           <Border .Projection>
              <PlaneProjection x:Name="planeProjection" CenterOfRotationY="1"/>
           </Border .Projection>         
        </Border>

        <Border Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="1">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

The problem is, here I am using two controls(Border), but I want to use animation on only one control i.e dividing the animation so that it applies to half part of the control(only one border)?

Guys help me.